# Windows 7 MSDNAA, install on more computers

Tags: windows-7, license

I have an MSDN Academic Alliance account from my university. I have downloaded from there Windows 7 x64 and I am currently using it on my desktop PC.

I recently bought a laptop, and I want to install Windows 7 x86 on it. But I have noticed that I get the same key for Windows 7 x86 and Windows 7 x64 from the site I use to get the Microsoft software (that site is e-academy.com)

So I have this question: Can I install Windows 7 x86 on my laptop, and Windows 7 x64 on my desktop, using the same key? Or will that get me into trouble when I reinstall Windows?

Comment: I know when I did the same thing I received separate keys for x86 and x64. I guess it either differs based on school, or they must have changed it :(

Comment: There is something strange going on here... I remember that I had the same key for x86 and x64, but now I went to the site and checked, and I have different keys for the different versions.
Oh well. Thank you guys anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key will work fine, however you should not install on more than the total number of computers you are allowed to use.

I believe that if it is for personal/research/education use, you may install it on as many computers as you wish... and keep it after you graduate - you simply are not allowed to install any more copies after you graduate and your MSDNAA expires.

Comment: In addition, while in school (and after you graduate) the install is only good for personal/academic purposes - not commercial purposes.

Comment: So, after I graduate, if I want to reinstall my PC, activation will fail?

Comment: Technically no, but you will be braking the licensing agreement.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're licensed, a single key isn't particularly unusual. I haven't dealt with MSDNAA in about 5 or 6 years, but my company is enrolled in MAPS and Microsoft issues us a single CD key for Win7 Pro for 32/64 bit with 10 licenses. Same deal with their other volume licensing programs I've dealt with.

Comment: i don't think MSDNAA is under volume licensing